# Java StopWatch timer won't stop

Tags: java, timer, stopwatch

I got a StopWatch class, I want to implement the Lap function

When the Run/Stop button is pressed, a timer begins counting on the display. If
the Run/Stop button is pressed again, the timer stops. If it is pressed again, the
timer resumes counting , and so on.
If the Lap/Reset button is pressed while the timer is running, the display
freezes, and shows the lap-time, and the timer continues to count (it just isn’t
displayed). If the Lap/Reset button is pressed again, the display resumes displaying
the timer in real time. If the Lap/Reset button is pressed the display
freezes, and so on.
If the Lap/Reset button is pressed while the timer is running, the display
freezes, (but the timer keeps running). If now the Run/Stop button is pressed,
the timer stops counting, but the display continues to show the lap-time. If the
Lap/Reset button is pressed, the display then changes to show the timer (which
is now stopped). If now the Run/Stop button is pressed the timer resumes
counting. Alternatively, if the Lap/Reset button is pressed, the timer is reset to
zero.

```
public void startStop() {

    timer = new Timer(100, new TimerHandler());
    if (!isRunning) {
        isRunning = true;
        timer.start();
    } else {
        isRunning = false;
        timer.stop();
    }
    //If now the Run/Stop button is pressed the timer resumes counting
    if(!lapPress && !isRunning){
        isRunning = true;
    }

}

public void lapReset() {
    if (!lapPress) {
        lapPress = true;
    } else if (lapPress) {
        lapPress = false;
    } 

    System.out.println(isRunning + " " + lapPress);

    // Lap pressed + timer running -> show lap-time + timer continue
    if (isRunning && lapPress) {
        timer.stop();
    }
    // Lap press + timer running
    if (isRunning && !lapPress) {
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

I just can't get my lap function work. The basic stopwatch is working fine, any idea? I updated the requirements, just want to check my logic for the button press, now If I click start and lap the display will freeze, but if I click start start and lap the display will continue update.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Does Apache Commons's [StopWatch](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/StopWatch.html) class do what you need?

Comment: Your stop watch won't keep very good time, `Thread.sleep` not accurate enough for timing purposes - http://www.javatuning.com/why-is-thread-sleep-inherently-inaccurate

Answer (score 0):

Is `running` volatile?  If suspect it is not which means that the thread can cache the value or even inline it which means it won't see the changes, possibly never see them.

http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2013/01/java-memory-model-and-optimisation.html